# How to request permission for a canvas application using Facebook PHP SDK v4

Tags: php, facebook-graph-api, facebook-php-sdk

I'm wondering how to correctly ask for permissions (publish_actions), with a canvas application using the Facebook PHP SDK v4.

Answer (score 0):

Asking for permission is the same as other apps:

```
// set redirect_uri
$helper = new FacebookRedirectLoginHelper( 'http://apps.facebook.com/yourapp' );

// login link
echo '<a href="' . $helper->getLoginUrl( [ 'publish_actions' ] ) . '" target="_top">Login</a>';
```